# Different Category Headers using in_category and elseif

Tags: categories

At the moment I'm trying to figure out why this snippet is not working basically I want to display a div id for different categories. I'm using the following.

```
 <?php if (in_category( array('6,14,15,13') )) { ?>
 <div id="eatheader">

 <?php } elseif (in_category( array('7,11,12,10,9') )) { ?>
 <div id="goheader">

 <?php } elseif (in_category( array('4,16,17,18,19') )) { ?>
 <div id="playheader">

 <?php } elseif (in_category( array('3,22,21,26') )) { ?>
 <div id="shopheader">

 <?php } elseif (in_category( array('5') )) { ?>
 <div id="talkheader">

 <?php } else { ;?>
 <div id="defaultheader">

 <?php } ?>
```

But this is not working I'm getting the following error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/test/public_html/project/wp-content/themes/project/category.php on line 75

Line 75 is the

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: the posted code does not create an error - search somewhere else in your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unnecessary semi-colon is probably causing the error. `<?php } else { ;?>` should be `<?php } else { ?>`. Try this:

```
<?php if (in_category( array(6,14,15,13) )) { ?>
<div id="eatheader">

<?php } elseif (in_category( array(7,11,12,10,9) )) { ?>
<div id="goheader">

<?php } elseif (in_category( array(4,16,17,18,19) )) { ?>
<div id="playheader">

<?php } elseif (in_category( array(3,22,21,26) )) { ?>
<div id="shopheader">

<?php } elseif (in_category(5)) { ?>
<div id="talkheader">

<?php } else { ?>
<div id="defaultheader">

<?php } ?>
```

As you can see, I've also modified `<?php } elseif (in_category( array('5') )) { ?>` to `<?php } elseif (in_category(5)) { ?>` as you are specifying just one category.

The same code can be rewritten to this (just in case it's useful to you—more readable and understandable):

```
<?php

    if ( in_category( array( 6,14,15,13 ) ) ) {
        echo '<div id="eatheader">';
    }

    elseif ( in_category( array( 7,11,12,10,9 ) ) ) {
        echo '<div id="goheader">';
    }

    elseif ( in_category( array( 4,16,17,18,19 ) ) ) {
        echo '<div id="playheader">';
    }

    elseif ( in_category( array( 3,22,21,26 ) ) ) {
        echo '<div id="shopheader">';
    }

    elseif ( in_category( 5 ) ) {
        echo '<div id="talkheader">';
    }

    else {
        echo '<div id="defaultheader">';
    }

?>
```

Comment: the 'same code can be rewritten' will lead to an error message because it mixes html and php code.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, right. Don't know what I was thinking... thanks for the headsup though, corrected. :)